# develop and master branches not visible remotely on VSTS

Tags: azure-devops, branch, git-flow, jgitflow-maven-plugin

The first picture displays that I have only one feature branch on VSTS:

[image]

The second picture displays that I have develop and master branches as well in visual studio locally:

[image]

There were master and develop branches on remote before, but seems to disappear suddenly. My commit history does not show any clue of them being merged into the feature, How do i find out what has happened? I want to avoid merge conflicts

Comment: Were any restrictions put in place at the server repo level for those branches?

Comment: There were no restrictions on the server side. The same branches existed when the project initially started but they don't now. Is there a way to find out?

Comment: Hi Patrick, I could not figure out why it was not visible, but I had to check out those branches individually and push them to the remote repo to make them visible. I did not find any merge conflicts so I believe it was hidden or removed from VSTS

Comment: @Azmeena If you could not see these two branches ,how do you perform the merge action in server side, using command line? Besides, what's the result if you try to fetch code from these two  server repos, did you get any error info?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, someone/others may deleted the branch in server side. VSTS will not auto delete your branch.

You could double check this through **search** option, enter your branch name here such as develop.

[image]

If the branch status is deleted ,you could select the ... option and choose recover the branch, finally sync local changes with server repo.

Another possibility, you have selected the wrong remote repo. You may pushed the branch to another repo than the one you selected now.